# Append and prepend text nodes to a HTML element using DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, append, prepend

Here is my HTML code

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <div>A sample block <div>and child block</div></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I use DOM to append and prepend text nodes to the BODY elements without hurting its siblings?

```
$dom = new DOMdocument();    
@$dom->loadHTML($html);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);
```

like this

```
<html> 
    <body>
        Newly prepended text
        <div>A sample block <div>and child block</div></div>
        Newly appended text    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw you don't need HTML entities to display HTML in your post. Just intend any code by 4 spaces or just mark your code and click the `{}` button. See my edit as example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create text nodes with [`DOMText`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) (or by using [`DOMDocument::createTextNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php)):

```
$before = new DOMText('Newly prepended text');
// $before = $dom->createTextNode('Newly prepended text');
$after = new DOMText('Newly appended text');
// $after = $dom->createTextNode('Newly appended text');
```

Now, appending is just:

```
$body->appendChild($after);
```

For prepending, we can use [`DOMNode::firstChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.firstchild) to get the first child of the body and [`DOMNode::insertBefore`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php):

```
$body->insertBefore($before, $body->firstChild);
```

Comment: In case anyone came here trying to find how to do this with JavaScript, you can just use [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) on the parent node.